# Javascript Countdown Clock every Saturday at 11AM

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have a request to make that looks a little different than most the answers I found on here. I am looking for a Javascript countdown clock that repeats itself every Saturday at 11AM based on the server's clock, with the exception that the server is in CA, and the clock needs to be in EST. I forked this other clock as a start, however I am lost when it comes to creating a weekly schedule, instead of hard coded dates. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrVXNE

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00BF96;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00816A;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638906/get-date-of-specific-day-of-the-week-in-javascript to calculate the nearest Saturday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this to get the next saturaday at 11am date:

```
function getNextSaturday() {
   var now = new Date();
   var nextSaturday = new Date();
   nextSaturday.setDate(now.getDate() + (6 - 1 - now.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
   nextSaturday.setHours(11, 0, 0, 0);
   return nextSaturday;
}
```

And this to convert it to EST timezone:

```
function convertToEST(date){
    estOffset = -4.0 // -5 + 1 daylight savings
    utc = date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    return new Date(utc + (3600000 * estOffset));
}
```

All in all:

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

function getNextSaturday() {
   var now = new Date();
   var nextSaturday = new Date();
   nextSaturday.setDate(now.getDate() + (6 - 1 - now.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
   nextSaturday.setHours(11, 0, 0, 0);
   return nextSaturday;
}

function convertToEST(date){
    estOffset = -5.0
    utc = date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    return new Date(utc + (3600000 * estOffset));
}

var deadline = getNextSaturday();
initializeClock('clockdiv', convertToEST(deadline));
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00BF96;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00816A;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks great. 

Now can we add to that, and somehow have a "LIVE NOW" button show up between the hours of 11AM-1PM, and then have the clock reset after 1PM?

Comment: Thanks, so if it answered your question i'd appreciate if you accept it. Regarding your new question, get the now date in EST using the function above and simply check if `getDay() === 6` and `11 <= getHours() <= 13`

Comment: Great! Thank you Daniel.

Comment: Daniel, just up until recently this script worked until DST moved +1 hour forward. Do you know how I can fix this so the time is correct?

Comment: Just change the `estOffset` from `-5.0` to `-4.0`. edited.

Comment: I don't mean to bug you Daniel, but what can I do if I need to use an array of times against the countdown clock?

Comment: Any idea about my last comment? Thanks.