# Countdown to every saturday in Javascript, then open a 3 hour bracket?

Tags: javascript, countdown

I want to make a countdown to each saturday in the month. Once it reaches 1pm on Saturday, I would like a 3 hour bracket to open and the text would say "Bracket Open".

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: check this question and answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587387/javascript-countdown-clock-every-saturday-at-11am

Comment: that example already check every seconds you just need a little control in setHours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Date() object in javascript:

```
<script>
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();//1-7
var h = d.getHours();//0-23 
if(n==6&h==13){alert('Bracket Open'+h);}
</script>
```